# How to increment the Counter on Bulk array field mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset Like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("2q9abf6b3b758dbed05d4875"),
        "fruit" : "APPLE",
        "count" : 0,
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("2q9abf6b3b758dbed05d4876"),
        "fruit" : "MANGO",
        "count" : 0,
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("2q9abf6b3b758dbed05d4877"),
        "fruit" : "BANANA",
        "count" : 0,
}
```

I want to Make the counter increment by 1 which I already Know. My Problem is How I can Increment the Counters for Bulk.

Lets Say I have an Array on which value is

```
array = ['APPLE', 'BANANA'];
```

Now I want to increment the counter of only those element which are present on array.

So After array, desired result will be like this.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("2q9abf6b3b758dbed05d4875"),
        "fruit" : "APPLE",
        "count" : 1,
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("2q9abf6b3b758dbed05d4876"),
        "fruit" : "MANGO",
        "count" : 0,
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("2q9abf6b3b758dbed05d4877"),
        "fruit" : "BANANA",
        "count" : 1,
}
```

NOTE: This is Just a Basic Example. Array can hold Upto 50 entries or more than that. What will be the Best appreoach.
I am on Nodejs-Express Environment using mongoose for MongoDB. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Model.updateMany({ 'fruit': { '$in': array } }, { '$inc': { 'count': 1 } }, callbackFunc);`?

Comment: @chridam Thank You so much For your Help

Answer (score 0):

a possible approach would be to query the database for all docs which hold a fruit value that matches any of the values in the array you have. then loop over the returned array of objects.

```
YourModel.find({fruit: { $in: yourArray }}, function(err, foundFruits){
    if (err){
        //handle error
    }
    foundFruits.forEach(function(fruit){
        //make all the changes you want to make here
        //for example, incrementing counter:
        fruit.counter += 1;
        fruit.save();
    });
});
```

do note that if all you want to do is increment the counter, and no other changes, then you can simply use the [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) option in your query, or as chridam suggested, the $inc option